# Is there a way to remove multiple attribute to a doctrine ObjectSelect?

Tags: php, annotations, doctrine, zend-framework2

I have 3 tables, User, Roles and UserRoles. A User can have only one Role, but I didn't want to add a column for the role in the User table, the problem is that I want to add an ObjectSelect un the user form, but it is printing it as a multiple Select, which I don't want, I tried adding removeAttribute('multiple') but I get an error saying that:

"FormSelect does not allow specifying multiple selected values when the element does not have a multiple attribute set to a boolean true"

Adding multiple:false, doesn't work neither, so I'm trying to figure it out, this is the code.

User Entity:

```
/**
 * @ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity="Auth\Entity\User\Roles")
 * @ORM\JoinTable(name="userRole",
 *      joinColumns={@ORM\JoinColumn(name="idUser", referencedColumnName="id", unique=true)},
 *      inverseJoinColumns={@ORM\JoinColumn(name="idRole", referencedColumnName="id")}
 *      )
 * @Annotation\Type("Zend\Form\Element\ObjectSelect")
 * @Annotation\Required({"required":"true"})     
 * @Annotation\Options({"label":"Rol","target_class":"Auth\Entity\User\Roles","property":"name"})     
 * @Annotation\Attributes({"class":"form-control"})
 **/
private $roles;

public function __construct() {
    $this->roles = new ArrayCollection();
}

public function getRoles()
{
    return $this->roles->getValues();
}
```

AdminController add action:

```
public function addUserAction () {
    $view = new ViewModel();
    $userEntity = new User();
    $em = $this->entityManager();
    $builder = new DoctrineAnnotationBuilder($em);

    $form = $builder->createForm($userEntity);
    $form->setHydrator(new DoctrineHydrator($em, 'Users\Entity\User'));
    $form->bind($userEntity);
    $request = $this->getRequest();
    if ($request->isPost()) {
        $form->setData($request->getPost());
        if ($form->isValid()) {
            $em->persist($userEntity);
            $em->flush();
        }
    }
    $view->form = $form;
    return $view;
}
```

And my view:

```
$form = $this->form;
$form->setAttribute('action', $this->url('admin', array('action' => 'addUser')));

$form->prepare();
echo $this->form()->openTag($form);
echo $this->formRow($form->get('username'));
echo $this->formRow($form->get('email'));
echo $this->formRow($form->get('roles'));

echo $this->formSubmit($form->get('submit'));
echo $this->form()->closeTag();
```

Answer (score 0):

If a User can only have one Role, why a Many to Many relation?

The error raises when the Select is rendering. There's a moment where [the ObjectSelect value is validated](https://github.com/zendframework/zf2/blob/master/library/Zend/Form/View/Helper/FormSelect.php#L124) through the function **validateMultiValue**.

The function code is:

```
protected function validateMultiValue($value, array $attributes)
{
    if (null === $value) {
        return array();
    }

    if (!is_array($value)) {
        return (array) $value;
    }

    if (!isset($attributes['multiple']) || !$attributes['multiple']) {
        throw new Exception\DomainException(sprintf(
            '%s does not allow specifying multiple selected values when the element does not have a multiple attribute set to a boolean true',
            __CLASS__
        ));
    }

    return $value;
}
```

The way you've defined your user entity, you'll always have an array:

```
(...)
public function __construct() {
    $this->roles = new ArrayCollection();
}
(...)
```

So it always arrives to the last if, where it checks the **multiple** attribute. Because of you don't want it to be multiple, you set this property to false, and that's when the error raises. If it validates an array, the select is expected to be multiple.

If you change the relation, your code should work. You could try a Many to One. This way, from the role entity, you could get all the users with XXX role. And from the user side, you could get the ONLY role the user has.

---

**Edit:**

Sorry, now I see why you have a Many to Many relation. It's One to Many relation with join table. It seems that there's no a One to One with join table... The usual way to do it I think it should be to put the **role** column in the **User** table, but you can't. You need the **roles** property to be a **Role** entity, not an array of **Role** entities.

---